# How to convert this date format in php?

Tags: php, date, date-format

I receive this date format from facebook and google docs:

```
2011-02-25T10:55:25+0000
```

How can I convert it to something like

```
25/02/2011 10:55:25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get timestamp.

```
$ts = strtotime('2011-02-25T10:55:25+0000');
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $ts);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2011-02-25T10:55:25+0000');

print $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');

?>
```

Please don't forget to set the correct time zone with this example. Refer to the datetime documentation on the php.net site for more details.

Comment: Note that DateTime is only available on PHP 5.3

Comment: Yes, thanks for the info there I forgot to mention. Actually I think its also available in 5.2.5, but please correct me if I am wrong. I have been using it on 5.2.5 servers with no problems.

Comment: thanks ... I always use the php reference because I can't remember all the substitution chars.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like [SOAP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) format.

Try to read it in with [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) and give it out with your own format.

Look at [ZeSimon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143445/how-to-convert-this-date-format-in-php/5143512#5143512) for the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
$out = preg_replace( "/^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)T([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/", "\$3/\$2/\$1 \$4", $in );
```